# One child of div scrollable one fixed position

Tags: html, css, user-interface

I'm just now learning how to use SASS and CSS and I'm having some serious problems figuring out how to make the inside of a chat div scrollable while having the input field at the bottom stay when the scrolling happens. Although I figured out how to keep the bottom input bar fixed, now 2 things happen :

```
 1. The whole div does not scroll anymore
 2. Being fixed, now the width of the bottom bar is the same as the screen size since it is 100%, although I need it to be the same as its parent div.
```

I feel like I'm definitely missing something that a person that knows CSS would spot in a second, but I have spent hours trying to figure it out and still have not. The following is my CSS/HTML : [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gcollelu/h1f0ej1n/1/)

Here's my code :

```css
#frame {
  width: calc(100% + 30px);
  min-width: 360px;
  height: 92vh;
  min-height: 300px;
  background: #E6EAEA;
  margin-left: -15px;
  margin-right: -15px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 360px) {
  #frame {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
  }
}

#frame .content {
  float: right;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 735px) {
  #frame .content {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 300px !important;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 900px) {
  #frame .content {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

#frame .content .contact-profile {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  background: #f5f5f5;
}

#frame .content .contact-profile img {
  width: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  float: left;
  margin: 9px 12px 0 9px;
}

#frame .content .contact-profile p {
  float: left;
}

.contact-profile {
  overflow: hidden;
}

#frame .content .messages {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: calc(100% - 60px);
  max-height: calc(100% - 60px);
  overflow: hidden;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 735px) {
  #frame .content .messages {
    max-height: calc(100% - 105px);
  }
}

#frame .content .messages::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 8px;
  background: transparent;
}

#frame .content .messages::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

#frame .content .messages ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  clear: both;
  float: left;
  margin: 15px 15px 5px 15px;
  width: calc(100% - 25px);
  font-size: 0.9em;
}

#frame .content .messages ul li:nth-last-child(1) {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#frame .content .messages ul li.sent img {
  margin: 6px 8px 0 0;
}

#frame .content .messages ul li.sent p {
  background: #435f7a;
  color: #f5f5f5;
}

#frame .content .messages ul li.replies img {
  float: right;
  margin: 6px 0 0 8px;
}

#frame .content .messages ul li.replies p {
  background: #f5f5f5;
  float: right;
}

#frame .content .messages ul li img {
  width: 22px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  float: left;
}

#frame .content .messages ul li p {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  max-width: 205px;
  line-height: 130%;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 735px) {
  #frame .content .messages ul li p {
    max-width: 300px;
  }
}

#frame .content .message-input {
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 99;
}

#frame .content .message-input .wrap {
  position: relative;
}

.chatinput {
  float: left;
  border: none;
  width: calc(100% - 40px);
  border-radius: 0;
  padding: 11px 32px 10px 8px;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  color: #32465a;
  resize: none;
}

.message-input {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.chatmessagesubmit {
  float: right;
  border: none;
  padding: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #32465a;
  color: #f5f5f5;
  &:hover {
    background: #435f7a;
  }
}

.section-year {
  float: right;
  width: 48%;
}

.section-college {
  width: 48%;
}

#msgs {
  padding: 0px;
  overflow: auto;
  height: fit-content;
}

#message_content {
  line-height: 13px;
  border: 1px solid #ced4da;
}

.panel {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}

#close_chat {
  float: right;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: 0px 12px 12px 12px;
}
```

```html
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/all.js"></script>
<div id="frame">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="contact-profile">
      <img src="https://www.drupal.org/files/profile_default.png" alt="Dsc 1809">
      <p>Chatroom test</p>
      <div id="close_chat">
        <a data-remote="true" href="/pages/close_chatroom?method=get">
          <div style="color:#435f7a; cursor:pointer;">
            <svg class="svg-inline--fa fa-window-close fa-w-16" aria-hidden="true" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="window-close" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512" data-fa-i2svg=""><path fill="currentColor" d="M464 32H48C21.5 32 0 53.5 0 80v352c0 26.5 21.5 48 48 48h416c26.5 0 48-21.5 48-48V80c0-26.5-21.5-48-48-48zm-83.6 290.5c4.8 4.8 4.8 12.6 0 17.4l-40.5 40.5c-4.8 4.8-12.6 4.8-17.4 0L256 313.3l-66.5 67.1c-4.8 4.8-12.6 4.8-17.4 0l-40.5-40.5c-4.8-4.8-4.8-12.6 0-17.4l67.1-66.5-67.1-66.5c-4.8-4.8-4.8-12.6 0-17.4l40.5-40.5c4.8-4.8 12.6-4.8 17.4 0l66.5 67.1 66.5-67.1c4.8-4.8 12.6-4.8 17.4 0l40.5 40.5c4.8 4.8 4.8 12.6 0 17.4L313.3 256l67.1 66.5z"></path></svg>
            <!-- <i class="fas fa-window-close" aria-hidden="true"></i> -->
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="messages panel-body" id="messages">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <ul id="msgs">

          <li class="sent">
            <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
            <p>You ready for Kenya?</p>
          </li>
          <li class="replies">
            <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/008/thumb/profile_picture.JPG?1519240015" alt="Profile picture">
            <p>whaddup
            </p>
          </li>
          <li class="sent">
            <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
            <p>lol</p>
          </li>
          <li class="sent">
            <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
            <p>gretgr</p>
          </li>
          <li class="sent">
            <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
            <p>rethgthyteh
            </p>
          </li>
          <li class="sent">
            <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
            <p>rewgergewrg</p>
          </li>
          <li class="sent">
            <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
            <p>erqfwere</p>
          </li>
          <li class="sent">
            <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
            <p>refsrtagrwt</p>
          </li>
          <li class="sent">
            <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
            <p>brdsgergser</p>
          </li>
          <li class="sent">
            <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
            <p>test lolollo</p>
          </li>
          <li class="sent">
            <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen
              book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more
              recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum</p>
          </li>
          <li class="sent">
            <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen
              book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more
              recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum</p>
          </li>
          <li class="sent">
            <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen
              book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more
              recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum</p>
          </li>
          <li class="sent">
            <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
            <p>So my question; Is it neater to loose the "=== true" part in the future, or is it good practise to check the type of the variable as well.</p>
          </li>
          <li class="sent">
            <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
            <p>Then, what Javascript will do is type coerce true to match the type of someVar and then compare the two variables. There are lots of situations where this is likely not what one would intend. Because of this, in most cases you want to avoid
              == because there's a fairly long set of rules on how Javascript will type coerce two things to be the same type and unless you understand all those rules and can anticipate everything that the JS interpreter might do when given two different
              types (which most JS developers cannot), you probably want to avoid == entirely.</p>
          </li>
          <li class="sent">
            <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
            <p>m going to accept this answer because it works for my example. It still doesnt work for my actual app because I need to append an HTML string to the view node and appendChild needs a DOM node not a string</p>
          </li>
          <li class="sent">
            <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
            <p>Then, what Javascript will do is type coerce true to match the type of someVar and then compare the two variables. There are lots of situations where this is likely not what one would intend. Because of this, in most cases you want to avoid
              == because there's a fairly long set of rules on how Javascript will type coerce two things to be the same type and unless you understand all those rules and can anticipate everything that the JS interpreter might do when given two different
              types (which most JS developers cannot), you probably want to avoid == entirely.</p>
          </li>
          <li class="sent">
            <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
            <p> dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essential</p>
          </li>
          <li class="sent">
            <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
            <p>But this will only send the name attribute and its value for the specific input field, not the rest of the form input fields. What if I want to send all the form input fields to the server, how can I do that without a form button (I just want
              to tab out of the specified input field).</p>
          </li>
          <li class="sent">
            <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
            <p>strhtyhh</p>
          </li>
          <li class="sent">
            <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
            <p>test</p>
          </li>
          <li class="sent">
            <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
            <p>erggrdgssggr</p>
          </li>
          <li class="sent">
            <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
            <p>test</p>
          </li>
          <li class="sent">
            <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
            <p>rthtdfhtftt</p>
          </li>
          <li class="sent">
            <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
            <p>favssvsfsvdsdf</p>
          </li>
          <li class="sent">
            <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
            <p>erfqerferqerqer</p>
          </li>
          <li class="sent">
            <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
            <p>loool whats up</p>
          </li>
          <li class="sent">
            <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
            <p>dssfgbhhg</p>
          </li>
          <li class="sent">
            <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
            <p>fvdxfbfgsbbfg</p>
          </li>
          <li class="sent">
            <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
            <p>test</p>
          </li>
          <li class="sent">
            <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
            <p>sgresggstsrt</p>
          </li>
          <li class="sent">
            <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
            <p>sgrrttgtg</p>
          </li>
          <li class="sent">
            <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
            <p>sgrrttgtg</p>
          </li>
          <li class="sent">
            <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
            <p>test</p>
          </li>
          <li class="sent">
            <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
            <p>test</p>
          </li>
          <li class="sent">
            <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
            <p>this should be one</p>
          </li>
          <li class="sent">
            <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
            <p>this should be one</p>
          </li>
          <li class="sent">
            <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
            <p>okay stop</p>
          </li>
          <li class="sent">
            <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
            <p>okay stop</p>
          </li>
          <li class="sent">
            <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
            <p>whaaaat</p>
          </li>
          <li class="sent">
            <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
            <p>whaaaat</p>
          </li>
          <li class="sent">
            <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
            <p>dammit</p>
          </li>
          <li class="sent">
            <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
            <p></p>
          </li>
          <li class="sent">
            <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
            <p>lafhjgefbjhe</p>
          </li>
          <li class="sent">
            <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
            <p>dammit</p>
          </li>
          <li class="sent">
            <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
            <p>two</p>
          </li>
          <li class="sent">
            <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
            <p></p>
          </li>
          <li class="sent">
            <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
            <p></p>
          </li>
          <li class="sent">
            <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
            <p>gergaregera</p>
          </li>
          <li class="sent">
            <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
            <p>hello world</p>
          </li>
          <li class="sent">
            <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
            <p>hello</p>
          </li>
          <li class="sent">
            <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
            <p>klhli</p>
          </li>
          <li class="sent">
            <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
            <p>fuck</p>
          </li>
          <li class="sent">
            <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
            <p></p>
          </li>
          <li class="sent">
            <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
            <p>teeeeeest</p>
          </li>
          <li class="sent">
            <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
            <p>okay fuck</p>
          </li>
          <li class="sent">
            <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
            <p>okay whaat</p>
          </li>
          <li class="sent">
            <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
            <p></p>
          </li>
          <li class="sent">
            <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
            <p>hfgdhfgd</p>
          </li>
          <li class="sent">
            <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
            <p>test</p>
          </li>
          <li class="sent">
            <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
            <p>hgdhkgfk</p>
          </li>
          <li class="sent">
            <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
            <p>fgdgfd</p>
          </li>
          <li class="sent"><img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384">
            <p>what</p>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="message-input">
        <form id="new_message" class="new_message" action="/messages" accept-charset="UTF-8" data-remote="true" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓"><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="MRkySbssrxg5xE+AU7+38wbjAFRVnUzsJMLIm5fP0Lea4tXpvafDBXDvXiFS4Vt0crPyISFYtP5nayMsBzt+UA==">
          <textarea class="form-control chatinput" placeholder="Write a message..." data-textarea="message" required="required" name="message[content]" id="message_content"></textarea>
          <input value="5" type="hidden" name="message[chatroom_id]" id="message_chatroom_id">
          <button name="button" type="submit" class="chatmessagesubmit" id="register-button" data-disable-with="Please wait..." data-send="message">
        <svg class="svg-inline--fa fa-paper-plane fa-w-16" aria-hidden="true" data-prefix="fa" data-icon="paper-plane" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512" data-fa-i2svg=""><path fill="currentColor" d="M476 3.2L12.5 270.6c-18.1 10.4-15.8 35.6 2.2 43.2L121 358.4l287.3-253.2c5.5-4.9 13.3 2.6 8.6 8.3L176 407v80.5c0 23.6 28.5 32.9 42.5 15.8L282 426l124.6 52.2c14.2 6 30.4-2.9 33-18.2l72-432C515 7.8 493.3-6.8 476 3.2z"></path></svg><!-- <i class="fa fa-paper-plane" aria-hidden="true"></i> -->
</button>
        </form>


      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `position:fixed` will fixed the element with respect to the document not to parent element....so you will need to use `position:absolute` here...

The idea is here to give the `height` to `.messages` div equal to `calc(100% - 60px)` with `position:relative` and apply `position:absolute` to the `.message-input` div...

Also I have removed the unwanted css from your code...

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#frame {
  background: #E6EAEA;
  height: 100vh;
}

#frame .content {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

#frame .content .message-input {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 10px 10px 5px;
}

#frame .content .contact-profile {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  background: #f5f5f5;
}

#frame .content .contact-profile img {
  width: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  float: left;
  margin: 9px 12px 0 9px;
}

#frame .content .contact-profile p {
  margin: 0;
}

#close_chat {
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: 0px 12px 12px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}

#frame .content .messages {
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100% - 60px);
  position: relative;
}

.panel {
  height: calc(100% - 67px); /* here 67px is message input height */
}

#msgs {
  padding: 0px;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

#frame .content .messages ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  clear: both;
  float: left;
  margin: 15px 15px 5px 15px;
  width: calc(100% - 25px);
  font-size: 0.9em;
}

#frame .content .messages ul li.sent img {
  margin: 6px 8px 0 0;
}

#frame .content .messages ul li img {
  width: 22px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  float: left;
}

#frame .content .messages ul li.sent p {
  background: #435f7a;
  color: #f5f5f5;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 735px) #frame .content .messages ul li p {
  max-width: 300px;
}

#frame .content .messages ul li p {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  max-width: 205px;
  line-height: 130%;
}

#frame .content .messages ul li.replies img {
  float: right;
  margin: 6px 0 0 8px;
}

#message_content {
  line-height: 13px;
  border: 1px solid #ced4da;
}

.chatinput {
  border: none;
  width: calc(100% - 52px);
  border-radius: 0;
  padding: 10px 30px 10px 10px;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  color: #32465a;
  resize: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.chatmessagesubmit {
  border: none;
  padding: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #32465a;
  color: #f5f5f5;
  vertical-align: top;
  height: 48px;
  width: 48px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/all.js"></script>
<div id="frame">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="contact-profile">
      <img src="https://www.drupal.org/files/profile_default.png" alt="Dsc 1809">
      <p>Chatroom test</p>
      <div id="close_chat">
        <a data-remote="true" href="/pages/close_chatroom?method=get">
          <div style="color:#435f7a; cursor:pointer;">
            <svg class="svg-inline--fa fa-window-close fa-w-16" aria-hidden="true" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="window-close" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512" data-fa-i2svg=""><path fill="currentColor" d="M464 32H48C21.5 32 0 53.5 0 80v352c0 26.5 21.5 48 48 48h416c26.5 0 48-21.5 48-48V80c0-26.5-21.5-48-48-48zm-83.6 290.5c4.8 4.8 4.8 12.6 0 17.4l-40.5 40.5c-4.8 4.8-12.6 4.8-17.4 0L256 313.3l-66.5 67.1c-4.8 4.8-12.6 4.8-17.4 0l-40.5-40.5c-4.8-4.8-4.8-12.6 0-17.4l67.1-66.5-67.1-66.5c-4.8-4.8-4.8-12.6 0-17.4l40.5-40.5c4.8-4.8 12.6-4.8 17.4 0l66.5 67.1 66.5-67.1c4.8-4.8 12.6-4.8 17.4 0l40.5 40.5c4.8 4.8 4.8 12.6 0 17.4L313.3 256l67.1 66.5z"></path></svg>
            <!-- <i class="fas fa-window-close" aria-hidden="true"></i> -->
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="messages panel-body" id="messages">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <ul id="msgs">

          <li class="sent">
            <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
            <p>You ready for Kenya?</p>
          </li>
          <li class="replies">
            <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/008/thumb/profile_picture.JPG?1519240015" alt="Profile picture">
            <p>whaddup
            </p>
          </li>
          <li class="sent">
            <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
            <p>lol</p>
          </li>
          <li class="sent">
            <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
            <p>gretgr</p>
          </li>
          <li class="sent">
            <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
            <p>rethgthyteh
            </p>
          </li>
          <li class="sent">
            <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
            <p>rewgergewrg</p>
          </li>
          <li class="sent">
            <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
            <p>erqfwere</p>
          </li>
          <li class="sent">
            <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
            <p>refsrtagrwt</p>
          </li>
          <li class="sent">
            <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
            <p>brdsgergser</p>
          </li>
          <li class="sent">
            <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
            <p>test lolollo</p>
          </li>
          <li class="sent">
            <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen
              book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more
              recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum</p>
          </li>
          <li class="sent">
            <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen
              book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more
              recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum</p>
          </li>
          <li class="sent">
            <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen
              book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more
              recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum</p>
          </li>
          <li class="sent">
            <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
            <p>So my question; Is it neater to loose the "=== true" part in the future, or is it good practise to check the type of the variable as well.</p>
          </li>
          <li class="sent">
            <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
            <p>Then, what Javascript will do is type coerce true to match the type of someVar and then compare the two variables. There are lots of situations where this is likely not what one would intend. Because of this, in most cases you want to avoid
              == because there's a fairly long set of rules on how Javascript will type coerce two things to be the same type and unless you understand all those rules and can anticipate everything that the JS interpreter might do when given two different
              types (which most JS developers cannot), you probably want to avoid == entirely.</p>
          </li>
          <li class="sent">
            <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
            <p>m going to accept this answer because it works for my example. It still doesnt work for my actual app because I need to append an HTML string to the view node and appendChild needs a DOM node not a string</p>
          </li>
          <li class="sent">
            <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
            <p>Then, what Javascript will do is type coerce true to match the type of someVar and then compare the two variables. There are lots of situations where this is likely not what one would intend. Because of this, in most cases you want to avoid
              == because there's a fairly long set of rules on how Javascript will type coerce two things to be the same type and unless you understand all those rules and can anticipate everything that the JS interpreter might do when given two different
              types (which most JS developers cannot), you probably want to avoid == entirely.</p>
          </li>
          <li class="sent">
            <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
            <p> dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essential</p>
          </li>
          <li class="sent">
            <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
            <p>But this will only send the name attribute and its value for the specific input field, not the rest of the form input fields. What if I want to send all the form input fields to the server, how can I do that without a form button (I just want
              to tab out of the specified input field).</p>
          </li>
          <li class="sent">
            <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
            <p>strhtyhh</p>
          </li>
          <li class="sent">
            <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
            <p>test</p>
          </li>
          <li class="sent">
            <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
            <p>erggrdgssggr</p>
          </li>
          <li class="sent">
            <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
            <p>test</p>
          </li>
          <li class="sent">
            <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
            <p>rthtdfhtftt</p>
          </li>
          <li class="sent">
            <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
            <p>favssvsfsvdsdf</p>
          </li>
          <li class="sent">
            <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
            <p>erfqerferqerqer</p>
          </li>
          <li class="sent">
            <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
            <p>loool whats up</p>
          </li>
          <li class="sent">
            <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
            <p>dssfgbhhg</p>
          </li>
          <li class="sent">
            <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
            <p>fvdxfbfgsbbfg</p>
          </li>
          <li class="sent">
            <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
            <p>test</p>
          </li>
          <li class="sent">
            <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
            <p>sgresggstsrt</p>
          </li>
          <li class="sent">
            <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
            <p>sgrrttgtg</p>
          </li>
          <li class="sent">
            <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
            <p>sgrrttgtg</p>
          </li>
          <li class="sent">
            <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
            <p>test</p>
          </li>
          <li class="sent">
            <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
            <p>test</p>
          </li>
          <li class="sent">
            <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
            <p>this should be one</p>
          </li>
          <li class="sent">
            <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
            <p>this should be one</p>
          </li>
          <li class="sent">
            <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
            <p>okay stop</p>
          </li>
          <li class="sent">
            <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
            <p>okay stop</p>
          </li>
          <li class="sent">
            <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
            <p>whaaaat</p>
          </li>
          <li class="sent">
            <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
            <p>whaaaat</p>
          </li>
          <li class="sent">
            <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
            <p>dammit</p>
          </li>
          <li class="sent">
            <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
            <p></p>
          </li>
          <li class="sent">
            <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
            <p>lafhjgefbjhe</p>
          </li>
          <li class="sent">
            <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
            <p>dammit</p>
          </li>
          <li class="sent">
            <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
            <p>two</p>
          </li>
          <li class="sent">
            <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
            <p></p>
          </li>
          <li class="sent">
            <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
            <p></p>
          </li>
          <li class="sent">
            <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
            <p>gergaregera</p>
          </li>
          <li class="sent">
            <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
            <p>hello world</p>
          </li>
          <li class="sent">
            <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
            <p>hello</p>
          </li>
          <li class="sent">
            <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
            <p>klhli</p>
          </li>
          <li class="sent">
            <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
            <p>fuck</p>
          </li>
          <li class="sent">
            <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
            <p></p>
          </li>
          <li class="sent">
            <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
            <p>teeeeeest</p>
          </li>
          <li class="sent">
            <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
            <p>okay fuck</p>
          </li>
          <li class="sent">
            <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
            <p>okay whaat</p>
          </li>
          <li class="sent">
            <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
            <p></p>
          </li>
          <li class="sent">
            <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
            <p>hfgdhfgd</p>
          </li>
          <li class="sent">
            <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
            <p>test</p>
          </li>
          <li class="sent">
            <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
            <p>hgdhkgfk</p>
          </li>
          <li class="sent">
            <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
            <p>fgdgfd</p>
          </li>
          <li class="sent"><img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384">
            <p>what</p>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="message-input">
        <form id="new_message" class="new_message" action="/messages" accept-charset="UTF-8" data-remote="true" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓"><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="MRkySbssrxg5xE+AU7+38wbjAFRVnUzsJMLIm5fP0Lea4tXpvafDBXDvXiFS4Vt0crPyISFYtP5nayMsBzt+UA==">
          <textarea class="form-control chatinput" placeholder="Write a message..." data-textarea="message" required="required" name="message[content]" id="message_content"></textarea>
          <input value="5" type="hidden" name="message[chatroom_id]" id="message_chatroom_id">
          <button name="button" type="submit" class="chatmessagesubmit" id="register-button" data-disable-with="Please wait..." data-send="message">
        <svg class="svg-inline--fa fa-paper-plane fa-w-16" aria-hidden="true" data-prefix="fa" data-icon="paper-plane" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512" data-fa-i2svg=""><path fill="currentColor" d="M476 3.2L12.5 270.6c-18.1 10.4-15.8 35.6 2.2 43.2L121 358.4l287.3-253.2c5.5-4.9 13.3 2.6 8.6 8.3L176 407v80.5c0 23.6 28.5 32.9 42.5 15.8L282 426l124.6 52.2c14.2 6 30.4-2.9 33-18.2l72-432C515 7.8 493.3-6.8 476 3.2z"></path></svg><!-- <i class="fa fa-paper-plane" aria-hidden="true"></i> -->
</button>
        </form>


      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's perfect, but is there a way for the scrollable div not to go all the way down to under the messsage-input? @bhuwan

Comment: @GiulioColleluori for this you will need to set a height to the `.panel` class `height: calc(100% - 67px)` where 67px is the height of the `.message-input`....Updated..!

Comment: That works! However, for some reason when I implement this view within my div it isn't scrollable anymore. Do you know what could be causing that?

Comment: @GiulioColleluori it might be your extra css for that div is conflicting with the current one....

Comment: I inspected it with chrome and it doesn't look like it. However, the body of our page isn't scrollable so my guess is that that's what it is conflicting with. Any way to override it?

Comment: @GiulioColleluori its hard to tell the issue from here as your whole code is not there....if body is not scrlling use `overflow:auto` in `body`

Answer (score 1):

**Is this you want ??**

```css
.notification_wrapper {
 margin-left: 20px;
 margin-right: 10px;
 float: left;
 position: relative;
}
.notification_wrapper .dropdown_notification .bell {
 cursor: pointer;
}
.notification_wrapper .dropdown_notification .notification_count span {
 color: #fff;
 background-color: #e5e5e5;
 border-radius: 4px;
 font-size: 12px;
 padding: 4px 8px;
 z-index: 99;
}
.notification_count span {
 margin-left: 15px;
 cursor: pointer;
 z-index: 99;
}
.notification_wrapper .dropdown_notification .notification_count span.unopened {
 background-color: #f87880;
}
.notification_wrapper.open .notification_list_wrapper {
 display: block;
}
.notification_wrapper .notification_list_wrapper {
 display: none;
 z-index: 999;
 width: 330px;
 height: 500px;
 border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
 position: absolute;
 top: calc(100% + 20px);
 right: -10px;
 background-color: #fff;
}
.notification_wrapper .notification_list_wrapper .notification_header_wrapper {
 position: relative;
 width: 330px;
 height: 37px;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 background-color: #fff;
}
.notification_wrapper .notification_list_wrapper .notification_header_wrapper .notification_header_title {
 position: absolute;
 top: 4px;
 left: 10px;
 font-size: 14px;
}
.notification_wrapper .notification_list_wrapper .notification_header_wrapper .notification_header_menu {
 position: absolute;
 top: 4px;
 right: 10px;
 font-size: 14px;
}
.notification_wrapper .notification_list_wrapper .notifications {
 position: relative;
 width: 330px;
 height: calc(500px - 37px - 37px);
 overflow: scroll;
}
.notification_wrapper .notification_list_wrapper .notification_link_wrapper {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 width: 330px;
 height: 26px;
 border-top: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
 padding: 4px 0 8px 0;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: #fff;
 z-index: 2;
}
.notification_wrapper .notification_list_wrapper .notification_link_wrapper:hover {
 background-color: #f8f9fb;
}
.notification_wrapper .notification_list_wrapper .notification_link_wrapper .notification_link {
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 14px;
}
.tabtitle {
 font-size: 1vw;
}
.center {
 text-align: center;
}
.oval-cell {
 margin-top: 10px;
 margin-left: 5px;
 margin-right: 5px;
 border-radius: 50px;
 width: 100%;
  background: $primary;
 padding-top: 10px;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
 padding-right: 15px;
 padding-left: 15px;
}
.cell-activity_name {
 margin-right: 10px;
}
.cell-profile_name {
 margin-right: 20px;
}
.myactivitiesmenu.show {
 height: 300px;
 overflow-y: auto;
 overflow-x: hidden;
}
#frame {
 width: calc(100% + 30px);
 min-width: 360px;
 height: 92vh;
 min-height: 300px;
 background: #E6EAEA;
 max-width: 100%;
,:
}

@media screen and (max-width: 360px) {
#frame {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100vh;
}
}
#frame .content {
 height: 100%;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 735px) {
 #frame .content {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 300px !important;
 }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 900px) {
#frame .content {
 width: 100%;
}
}
#frame .content .contact-profile {
 width: 100%;
 height: 60px;
 line-height: 60px;
 background: #f5f5f5;
}
#frame .content .contact-profile img {
 width: 40px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 float: left;
 margin: 9px 12px 0 9px;
}
#frame .content .contact-profile p {
 float: left;
}
.contact-profile {
 overflow: hidden;
}
#frame .content .messages {
 height: auto;
 width: 100%;
 min-height: calc(100% - 40px);
 max-height: calc(100% - 40px);
 overflow: scroll;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 735px) {
#frame .content .messages {
 max-height: calc(100% - 105px);
}
}
#frame .content .messages::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 8px;
  background: transparent;
}
#frame .content .messages::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
#frame .content .messages ul li {
 display: inline-block;
 clear: both;
 float: left;
 margin: 15px 15px 5px 15px;
 width: calc(100% - 25px);
 font-size: 0.9em;
}
#frame .content .messages ul li:nth-last-child(1) {
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}
#frame .content .messages ul li.sent img {
 margin: 6px 8px 0 0;
}
#frame .content .messages ul li.sent p {
 background: #435f7a;
 color: #f5f5f5;
}
#frame .content .messages ul li.replies img {
 float: right;
 margin: 6px 0 0 8px;
}
#frame .content .messages ul li.replies p {
 background: #f5f5f5;
 float: right;
}
#frame .content .messages ul li img {
 width: 22px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 float: left;
}
#frame .content .messages ul li p {
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 10px 15px;
 border-radius: 20px;
 max-width: 205px;
 line-height: 130%;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 735px) {
#frame .content .messages ul li p {
 max-width: 300px;
}
}
#frame .content .message-input {
 width: 100%;
 z-index: 99;
 bottom: 76px;
}
#frame .content .message-input form:after {
 content: '';
 clear: both;
 display: block;
}
#frame .content .message-input .wrap {
 position: relative;
}
.chatinput {
 float: left;
 border: none;
 width: calc(100% - 80px);
 border-radius: 0;
 padding: 5px 32px 5px 8px;
 text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
 font-size: 0.8em;
 color: #32465a;
 resize: none;
}
.message-input {
 position: fixed;
 bottom: 0;
 width: 100%;
}
.chatmessagesubmit {
 float: right;
 border: none;
 padding: 12px;
 cursor: pointer;
 background: #32465a;
 color: #f5f5f5;
}
.chatmessagesubmit:hover {
 background: #435f7a;
}
.section-year {
 float: right;
 width: 48%;
}
.section-college {
 width: 48%;
}
#msgs {
 padding: 0px;
 overflow: auto;
 height: fit-content;
 overflow: hidden;
}
#message_content {
 line-height: 13px;
 border: 1px solid #ced4da;
}
.panel {
 overflow: hidden;
 /* margin-bottom: 60px; */
 position: relative;
 z-index: 999;
}
#close_chat {
 float: right;
 font-size: 30px;
 margin: 0px 12px 12px 12px;
}

body {
 margin: 0; 
}
```

```html
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/all.js"></script>
<div id="frame">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="contact-profile"> <img src="https://www.drupal.org/files/profile_default.png" alt="Dsc 1809">
            <p>Chatroom test</p>
            <div id="close_chat"> <a data-remote="true" href="/pages/close_chatroom?method=get">
                <div style="color:#435f7a; cursor:pointer;">
                    <svg class="svg-inline--fa fa-window-close fa-w-16" aria-hidden="true" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="window-close" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512" data-fa-i2svg="">
                        <path fill="currentColor" d="M464 32H48C21.5 32 0 53.5 0 80v352c0 26.5 21.5 48 48 48h416c26.5 0 48-21.5 48-48V80c0-26.5-21.5-48-48-48zm-83.6 290.5c4.8 4.8 4.8 12.6 0 17.4l-40.5 40.5c-4.8 4.8-12.6 4.8-17.4 0L256 313.3l-66.5 67.1c-4.8 4.8-12.6 4.8-17.4 0l-40.5-40.5c-4.8-4.8-4.8-12.6 0-17.4l67.1-66.5-67.1-66.5c-4.8-4.8-4.8-12.6 0-17.4l40.5-40.5c4.8-4.8 12.6-4.8 17.4 0l66.5 67.1 66.5-67.1c4.8-4.8 12.6-4.8 17.4 0l40.5 40.5c4.8 4.8 4.8 12.6 0 17.4L313.3 256l67.1 66.5z"></path>
                    </svg>
                    <!-- <i class="fas fa-window-close" aria-hidden="true"></i> --> 
                </div>
                </a> </div>
        </div>
        <div class="messages panel-body" id="messages">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <ul id="msgs">
                    <li class="sent"> <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
                        <p>You ready for Kenya?</p>
                    </li>
                    <li class="replies"> <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/008/thumb/profile_picture.JPG?1519240015" alt="Profile picture">
                        <p>whaddup </p>
                    </li>
                    <li class="sent"> <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
                        <p>lol</p>
                    </li>
                    <li class="sent"> <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
                        <p>gretgr</p>
                    </li>
                    <li class="sent"> <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
                        <p>rethgthyteh </p>
                    </li>
                    <li class="sent"> <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
                        <p>rewgergewrg</p>
                    </li>
                    <li class="sent"> <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
                        <p>erqfwere</p>
                    </li>
                    <li class="sent"> <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
                        <p>refsrtagrwt</p>
                    </li>
                    <li class="sent"> <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
                        <p>brdsgergser</p>
                    </li>
                    <li class="sent"> <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
                        <p>test lolollo</p>
                    </li>
                    <li class="sent"> <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
                        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum</p>
                    </li>
                    <li class="sent"> <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
                        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum</p>
                    </li>
                    <li class="sent"> <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
                        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum</p>
                    </li>
                    <li class="sent"> <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
                        <p>So my question; Is it neater to loose the "=== true" part in the future, or is it good practise to check the type of the variable as well.</p>
                    </li>
                    <li class="sent"> <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
                        <p>Then, what Javascript will do is type coerce true to match the type of someVar and then compare the two variables. There are lots of situations where this is likely not what one would intend. Because of this, in most cases you want to avoid == because there's a fairly long set of rules on how Javascript will type coerce two things to be the same type and unless you understand all those rules and can anticipate everything that the JS interpreter might do when given two different types (which most JS developers cannot), you probably want to avoid == entirely.</p>
                    </li>
                    <li class="sent"> <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
                        <p>m going to accept this answer because it works for my example. It still doesnt work for my actual app because I need to append an HTML string to the view node and appendChild needs a DOM node not a string</p>
                    </li>
                    <li class="sent"> <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
                        <p>Then, what Javascript will do is type coerce true to match the type of someVar and then compare the two variables. There are lots of situations where this is likely not what one would intend. Because of this, in most cases you want to avoid == because there's a fairly long set of rules on how Javascript will type coerce two things to be the same type and unless you understand all those rules and can anticipate everything that the JS interpreter might do when given two different types (which most JS developers cannot), you probably want to avoid == entirely.</p>
                    </li>
                    <li class="sent"> <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
                        <p> dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essential</p>
                    </li>
                    <li class="sent"> <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
                        <p>But this will only send the name attribute and its value for the specific input field, not the rest of the form input fields. What if I want to send all the form input fields to the server, how can I do that without a form button (I just want to tab out of the specified input field).</p>
                    </li>
                    <li class="sent"> <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
                        <p>strhtyhh</p>
                    </li>
                    <li class="sent"> <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
                        <p>test</p>
                    </li>
                    <li class="sent"> <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
                        <p>erggrdgssggr</p>
                    </li>
                    <li class="sent"> <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
                        <p>test</p>
                    </li>
                    <li class="sent"> <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
                        <p>rthtdfhtftt</p>
                    </li>
                    <li class="sent"> <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
                        <p>favssvsfsvdsdf</p>
                    </li>
                    <li class="sent"> <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
                        <p>erfqerferqerqer</p>
                    </li>
                    <li class="sent"> <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
                        <p>loool whats up</p>
                    </li>
                    <li class="sent"> <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
                        <p>dssfgbhhg</p>
                    </li>
                    <li class="sent"> <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
                        <p>fvdxfbfgsbbfg</p>
                    </li>
                    <li class="sent"> <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
                        <p>test</p>
                    </li>
                    <li class="sent"> <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
                        <p>sgresggstsrt</p>
                    </li>
                    <li class="sent"> <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
                        <p>sgrrttgtg</p>
                    </li>
                    <li class="sent"> <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
                        <p>sgrrttgtg</p>
                    </li>
                    <li class="sent"> <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
                        <p>test</p>
                    </li>
                    <li class="sent"> <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
                        <p>test</p>
                    </li>
                    <li class="sent"> <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
                        <p>this should be one</p>
                    </li>
                    <li class="sent"> <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
                        <p>this should be one</p>
                    </li>
                    <li class="sent"> <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
                        <p>okay stop</p>
                    </li>
                    <li class="sent"> <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
                        <p>okay stop</p>
                    </li>
                    <li class="sent"> <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
                        <p>whaaaat</p>
                    </li>
                    <li class="sent"> <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
                        <p>whaaaat</p>
                    </li>
                    <li class="sent"> <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
                        <p>dammit</p>
                    </li>
                    <li class="sent"> <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
                        <p></p>
                    </li>
                    <li class="sent"> <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
                        <p>lafhjgefbjhe</p>
                    </li>
                    <li class="sent"> <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
                        <p>dammit</p>
                    </li>
                    <li class="sent"> <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
                        <p>two</p>
                    </li>
                    <li class="sent"> <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
                        <p></p>
                    </li>
                    <li class="sent"> <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
                        <p></p>
                    </li>
                    <li class="sent"> <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
                        <p>gergaregera</p>
                    </li>
                    <li class="sent"> <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
                        <p>hello world</p>
                    </li>
                    <li class="sent"> <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
                        <p>hello</p>
                    </li>
                    <li class="sent"> <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
                        <p>klhli</p>
                    </li>
                    <li class="sent"> <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
                        <p>fuck</p>
                    </li>
                    <li class="sent"> <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
                        <p></p>
                    </li>
                    <li class="sent"> <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
                        <p>teeeeeest</p>
                    </li>
                    <li class="sent"> <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
                        <p>okay fuck</p>
                    </li>
                    <li class="sent"> <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
                        <p>okay whaat</p>
                    </li>
                    <li class="sent"> <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
                        <p></p>
                    </li>
                    <li class="sent"> <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
                        <p>hfgdhfgd</p>
                    </li>
                    <li class="sent"> <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
                        <p>test</p>
                    </li>
                    <li class="sent"> <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
                        <p>hgdhkgfk</p>
                    </li>
                    <li class="sent"> <img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384" alt="Img 8496">
                        <p>fgdgfd</p>
                    </li>
                    <li class="sent"><img src="/system/users/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_8496.JPG?1520241384">
                        <p>what</p>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="message-input">
                <form id="new_message" class="new_message" action="/messages" accept-charset="UTF-8" data-remote="true" method="post">
                    <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓">
                    <input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="MRkySbssrxg5xE+AU7+38wbjAFRVnUzsJMLIm5fP0Lea4tXpvafDBXDvXiFS4Vt0crPyISFYtP5nayMsBzt+UA==">
                    <textarea class="form-control chatinput" placeholder="Write a message..." data-textarea="message" required name="message[content]" id="message_content"></textarea>
                    <input value="5" type="hidden" name="message[chatroom_id]" id="message_chatroom_id">
                    <button name="button" type="submit" class="chatmessagesubmit" id="register-button" data-disable-with="Please wait..." data-send="message">
                    <svg class="svg-inline--fa fa-paper-plane fa-w-16" aria-hidden="true" data-prefix="fa" data-icon="paper-plane" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512" data-fa-i2svg="">
                        <path fill="currentColor" d="M476 3.2L12.5 270.6c-18.1 10.4-15.8 35.6 2.2 43.2L121 358.4l287.3-253.2c5.5-4.9 13.3 2.6 8.6 8.3L176 407v80.5c0 23.6 28.5 32.9 42.5 15.8L282 426l124.6 52.2c14.2 6 30.4-2.9 33-18.2l72-432C515 7.8 493.3-6.8 476 3.2z"></path>
                    </svg>
                    <!-- <i class="fa fa-paper-plane" aria-hidden="true"></i> --> 
                    </button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! For the scrolling yes! But I cannot have the bottom bar on fixed for if I do it cannot inherit the width of its parent div, which I need since the parent is just part of a page that has dynamic size

Comment: I'm referring to the .message-input class @AnzilKhan

Comment: @GiulioColleluori ,  You mean you don't want `fixed` this one  `.message-input`  , right ??

Comment: Right!  @AnzilKhan

Comment: Well not really, I do want it fixed at the bottom, however, from my understanding, I cannot use position fixed unless there is a way to do that while also somehow giving it a width of 100% (of its parent). Ultimately, I would like the input bar not scrolling with the rest but at the same time it should also have the width of its parent. Does that make sense? @AnzilKhan

Comment: Let me try with my understanding. @GiulioColleluori

Comment: Thank you. That's the right concept, however, I saw the message-bar is fixed, would it still take the right width (the width of its parent) if its parent was smaller than the page size? Also, as now the message bar is not sticking to the bottom and the text scrolls behind it while I wanted the messages div to be on top of the bar if that's possible. I previously got to this point but couldn't fix it from here. :/ @AnzilKhan

Comment: @GiulioColleluori, if  `messages div to be on top of the bar` then you can't add message until scroll get bottom.

Comment: Yeah the new message function also calls scrolls so it scrolls up any time a new message is added. Is that what you mean?

Comment: No , Can you tell me what is the problem right now with my answer ?? @GiulioColleluori

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166652/discussion-between-giulio-colleluori-and-anzil-khan).

Answer (score 0):

You need to place div inside a relative div. Give the child width and height as per you want and overflow scrollable. And place a button with position absolute and bottom:0

```
<div class="parent">
<div class="child">
</div>
<button>Click</button>
</div>
```

SASS

```
.parent{
 position:relative

 .child{
 width: 300px;
 height: 500px;
 overflow: scroll;
 padding-bottom: 20px;
 }

 button{
 width: 300px;
 height:20px;
 position:absolute;
 bottom:0;
 }
}
```